# cambie la imagen de fondo al hacer click

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que al hacer click cambie la imagen de fondo y se pueda restablecer, soy nuevo, me piden una pagina con js y se me ocurrió esto, adjunto mi código:

HTML:

```html
<div id="cambiar_fondo">
   <button type="button" id="boton_color">CAMBIAR FONDO</button>
   <button type="button" id="boton_default">RESTABLECER FONDO</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
document.getElementById('boton_color').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.style.background-image.url('fondo_pagina_2.png');
});

document.getElementById('boton_default').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.body.style.background-image.url('fondo_pagina.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal como mencionan en la [**documentación**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp), la sintaxis correcta sería:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('tuImagen.png')";
```

Con esto ya lo obtendrías, por ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('boton_color').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png')";
});

document.getElementById('boton_default').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.imgur.com/ZnpyoVz.jpg')";
});
```

```html
<div id="cambiar_fondo">
   <button type="button" id="boton_color">CAMBIAR FONDO</button>
   <button type="button" id="boton_default">RESTABLECER FONDO</button>
</div>
```